# Problem: org-babel code does not work with R

Tags: org-mode

I have a frustrating problem: Just migrated to a new computer and now my org-mode does not work correctly anymore (now on OSX 10.14).

Executing the following code block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC R :results output 
getwd()
#+END_SRC
```

Results in: `/bin/bash: R: command not found`. I've setup  my `~/.bashrc` to link to my local `R` so that the `R` command works in an emacs shell  (`M-x shell`) however that still did not help executing org-babel code blocks in R :(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `(setq org-babel-R-command "/folder/which/contains --no-save")` to th e`.emacs` file fixed it. Found here https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-R.html#orgc55114f

Comment: On my Windows, I also needed to add this line: `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.2/bin/x64")))`